# C++ macro doesn't substitute?

Tags: c++, macros

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define gao falsegao
#define fun(entity) \
    void fun_##entity() \
    {                     \
        std::cout << #entity << std::endl; \
    }

fun(gao);

int main()
{
    fun_gao();
    return 0;
}
```

This program will compile and run at ease. But why? I have already defined `gao` as `falsegao`, shouldn't the generated function be `void fun_false_gao()`? And the output should be `false_gao`, too.

Please help me solve this puzzle, when will the substitution take place ? what's the principle behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a two-leveled `fun` macro

```
#define fun_(entity) \
    void fun_##entity() \
    {                     \
        std::cout << #entity << std::endl; \
    }

#define fun(entity) fun_(entity)
```

That will work as intended.

Rules of macro substitution of C++ language prevent preprocessor from recursively replacing macro names in tokens adjacent to `##` or `#` operators. You need an additional level of "isolation" to make sure that `gao` gets replaced with `falsegao` *before* it gets to `##` or `#`.

Answer (score 1):

No, the `##` operator has higher precedence than parameter substitution. Idiomatically it's wrapped inside a macro:

```
#define CAT_LITERAL( A, B ) A ## B
#define CAT( A, B ) CAT_LITERAL( A, B )
```

The same applies to the `#` operator.

```
#define STR_LITERAL( LIT ) # LIT
#define STR( PARAM ) STR_LITERAL( PARAM )
```

So your macro is defined:

```
#define fun(entity) \
    void CAT( fun_, entity ) () \
    {                     \
        std::cout << STR( entity ) << std::endl; \
    }
```